# Can I use list comprehension for this code?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to express 'result' in this code using list comprehension just for fun.

Do you think i can do this? or it's impossible?

```
import random
result = []
for i in range(6):
    num = random.randint(1, 45)
    if num not in result:
        result.append(num)
print(result)
```

I tried several times to make it, and reached this state.

```
result = [num if num not in result for i in range(6)]
```

Comment: What is result here?

Comment: If you are just getting unique values use a set instead.

Comment: `a=0`

`result = [a := random.randint(1, 45) for i in range(6) if a not in result]`

Comment: Missing `result = []` in your example.

Comment: `result = [x for _ in range(6) if (x:= random.randint(1, 45)) not in result]`

Comment: @adrianop01 NameError with that "solution"

Comment: @Pingu `result = random.sample(range(1,45), k=6) ` is not strictly equivalent to OP's code (which doesn't guarantee `len(result) == 6`)... whether that's what OP wants (???)

Comment: @Julien You're right. OP's code (if *result* is initialised) will generate **at most** 6 values whereas my suggestion to use *random.sample()* will produce exactly 6 values (subject the population size being appropriate with respect to *k*). However, that's fairly obviously not the intent

Comment: @СергейКох I modified my question more specifically. Is it enough to understand?

Comment: OP, Refer to the comment by @DenisRasulev for the correct answer. Only works for Python version >= 3.8 though.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty seems to be in your condition that you don't want duplicate numbers in your result. To counter this, you can first build the list, then remove the duplicates by casting it to a `set`, and finally cast it back to a `list` should you need that specific data type.

```
list(set([random.randint(1, 45) for _ in range(6)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set comprehnsion here and convert it to list.

```py
list({random.randint(1, 45) for i in range(6)})
```